RuntimeError: Event loop is closed when integrating Telegram with Rasa chatbot
I am trying to integrate Telegram with my Rasa chatbot, but I am encountering following error --> RuntimeError: Event loop is closed. It appears that the event loop in asyncio is closed, causing the integration to fail.
Environment Details:
Rasa Version: 3.6.19
Rasa SDK Version: 3.6.2
Python Version: 3.10.14
Operating System: Windows 10
aiogram Version: 2.15
aiohttp Version: 3.9.5
aiohttp-retry Version: 2.8.3

Here is my credentials.yml file:
telegram:
  access_token: "7006*******:AAFL**********A_4eUwho9jJUA21NAc"
  verify: "tickztat_bot"
  webhook_url: "https://fdf3-103-21-76-246.ngrok-free.app/webhooks/telegram/webhook"

Here is the Error I am facing
[2024-06-28 10:26:12 +0530] [17816] [ERROR] Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http://fdf3-103-21-76-246.ngrok-free.app/webhooks/telegram/webhook'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "handle_request", line 83, in handle_request
    )
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\telegram.py", line 225, in message
    credentials = await out_channel.get_me()
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 215, in get_me
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_ME, payload)
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1197, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 479, in _request
    handle = tm.start()
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 660, in start
    return self._loop.call_at(when, self.__call__)
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 732, in call_at
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\admin\miniconda3\envs\chat_backend\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed


Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

You have to show us your code with essential parts, with no private sections (redact it) - it almost sounds like you didn't have await something that keeps your task alive
